Thriller from the early to mid 1960's involving blackmailing an official over underage liason
The main character was a James Bondish type, whose martial art skills allowed him to see off some attackers even when drunk. After this, he was recruited into MI5 or similar, the Chief of which mixed Black Velvet with 'chilled champagne and Guinness drawn from the wood' when they met. I believe the plot also involved compromising or blackmailing an MP or dignitary after a liaison with a girl alleged to be under age, and who declared "Pax, you dirty beast".
I believe 'Frost' (no, not that one!) could possibly be in the title?

This is Frost (1967) by Andrew Hall.
Described as a "bawdy, acidly funny spy romp", it contains the immortal lines...

'Pax, you dirty beast,' she cried ecstatically.
'Oh, oh, leave off."
'Oh, oh, leave off. Double-pax!' 'What are you doing?' 'You double - brute.' She bit his ear. 'Love me, Tommy, 'she hissed. 'You'll catch cold. Put your clothes on.'


There's a sub-plot about blackmail involving a young girl

Why don’t you ask your son about the little girl he had last Sunday in
the wood. Looked like a good lay.


Spot on!  That's the one. Many thanks for answering my query. Much appreciated. Now  I even recall that cover, very 1967. Now I wonder if my library will be able to locate a copy..

P.S. I see that the cover was designed by Ian Dury

Sounds like the Callan books by James Mitchell.
Callan began as a TV Play called A Magnum For Schnieder. Four TV series and two movies followed. Mitchell also wrote several novels based on the character, the first being an adaptation of the original play, the rest being new stories.
Callan is a working class man, ex military, and ex criminal, He's a good barehand figher,  even against multiple opponents, and can kill unarmed. And he drinks heavily. He was recruited into The Section, a dirty tricks division of British Intelligence. The Section uses methods including blackmail, intimidation, framing their targets for crimes, and direct murder.
Here's a quote from the first novel.

In London it was Donner’s business to find out about Charlock. Charlock was a banker of genius, seconded to the Treasury, who had twice pulled back Great Britain from the very brink of devaluation. His one relaxation was going to bed simultaneously with a boy and a girl, and Charlock liked them young. Hunter made no moral judgments about it: Charlock’s hobby was a fact of insignificant size when set against the enormous fact of his ability to shore up his country’s economy. Hunter spotted the target, and put Callan on to it. Callan followed Donner to the flat of a girl whose passport said she was an actress. There was no record of her having appeared on any stage or screen.

Is this what you remember?

Thanks for your reply. A very good suggestion, but unfortunately it's not the one.  I remember the Callan series, and he was reluctantly re-recruited into service rather than new. Also,  I read the book I am seeking in the middle to late '60's, before Callan was published.
